# If $[f(a)-f(b)]^2≤|a-b|^3$ is true for any two distinct real numbers $a$ and $b$, then $f(x)$ is a

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Q. If $${(f(a)-f(b))}^2 \le {|a-b|}^3$$ is true for any two distinct real numbers $a$ and $b$, then $f(x)$ is a

A. constant function
B. linear function
C. quadratic function

D. cubic function
E. trigonometric function
F. Other

Answer: [A] $f(x)$ is a constant function.

There are no worked solutions to this question but I’m guessing you start off with the following: (as this question has got to do with calculus)

$∵$ $0≤[f(a)-f(b)]^2≤|a-b|^3$

$∴$ $0≤[f(a)-f(b)]^2/|a-b|^2 ≤|a-b|$

Then I assume you will try making it seem like the first principle; however, I am having trouble and I do not understand what to do next.

Comment: Try b = a+h and b = a-h. What do you notice about the limit as h goes to 0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're on the right track.

*Hint:* Use the hypothesis to get
$$
\left(\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\right)^2 \le h
$$
and conclude that $f$ is differentiable and $f'(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Comment: So basically if I can prove that $f'(x)=0$ is differentiable for any x, then f(x) is a constant function? Thank you. I will try attempting this question again.

Answer (score 0):

Hint (A bit too long for a comment):
Obviously by squeezing 
$$\lim_{a\to b}\left|\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b}\right|^2=0,$$
hence 
$$\lim_{a\to b}\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b}=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

For any two distinct real number $a$ and $b$

$∵0≤[f(a)−f(b)]2≤|a−b|30≤[f(a)−f(b)]2≤|a−b|3$
$∴ 0≤[f(a)−f(b)]2/|a−b|2≤|a−b|$

$√0≤√([f(a)-f(b)]^2/|a-b|^2 )≤√(|a-b|)$

$√0≤|f(a)-f(b)|/|a-b|≤√|a-b|$...$(1)$

Let $h$ = $a-b$. Then $a=b+h$

Substitute $a=b+h$ into $(1)$

$lim┬(h→0)⁡0≤lim┬(h→0)⁡〖([f(b+h)-f(b)])/(|h|)〗≤lim┬(h→0)⁡√(|h|)$...$(2)$
$|lim┬(h→0)⁡⁡〖([f(b+h)-f(b)])/(|h|)〗|= |f'(-b)|$

$∴$ $(2)$ gives 0≤|f^'(b)|≤0

$∵$ $f'(x)=0$ for any $xϵR$

$∴$ $f(x)$ is a constant function

Hope that helped you. Next time ask your teacher before you post something you do not understand. Teachers can explain face to face, which will help you more.

Comment: Thank you for your solutions; however, as I am still new with derivatives I do not understand how (2) gives 0 equal/less than f'(b) equal/less than zero.